# Can a sys admin view a VMware client without their knowledge?

Tags: remote-access

I recently started working in a office that has VMware virtual clients. Can the sys admin use VMware to view a client without their knowledge?

Comment: In a word, yes. And no, you can't detect it.

Comment: I thought as much. Is there any way to detect it? Also, is there a best practice on separating out those abilities from the sys admin?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Define `VMware virtual client`.  Define `view`.

Answer (score 2):

Tech Addict mentions it already but i think the issue goes further.

If you use system that are not administrated by yourself, the system administrator can **generally** get **all** the access that he desires if he is willing to put some effort into it (which most often isn't even needed).

This is the reason why system administrators are by far the most trusted persons inside any company which relies on IT infrastructure. This is not refuted by the fact that very often management is not aware of the trust they put into their administrators.

I can reassure you though. Most of the administrators that i met are living and working by something you might call a codex. They will be very reluctant to access any user data they are not explicitly allowed to monitor.

To add a personal note: I am working as an administrator for a small public body. Because people use our infrastructure for private stuff sometimes i possibly have access to ~200 private email accounts. I'd never take advantage of that because

1. The trust that is placed in me is the most valueable asset i have in this job. Why should i jeopardize it? If something bad would happen i would be the first person they'd suspect.
2. I am way to busy setting up this damn new IPA system.
3. I really don't care.

Answer (score 1):

It's not even a VMware issue, really, because if you're running Windows there are ways to view another user's desktop session without their knowledge, and if you're in Linux there are variants of X11 and Xfree86/x.org that can do it.

If you use the VMware vSphere client to view your VM through VMware Remote Console, and someone else opens a remote console in their vSphere client to the same machine, a yellow bar opens at the top of the console stating "there are now 2 active sessions" or some similar wording I don't recall off the top of my head.

But as stated, whether you're in VMware or not is of little consequence:  you can be viewed without your knowledge.